# jquery touch punch z index has no impact

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I am working on ipad drag and drop and i tried to make the draggable element visible on every other div but it works only in parent div, my code is:

```
$('#draggable').draggable({
  zIndex: 20,
  drag: function(event){...},
  helper: 'clone',
  position: 'absolute',
  owerflow: 'hidden'
})
```

the html code looks like something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div id="draggable"></div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div id="dropDiv"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

When i am dragging the element its visible in the first td where it normally is, but when i try to drag it over the `<div id="dropDiv"></div>` it goes under the "dropDiv".

These divs and tds have multiple css classes which i cant display here.

I have already tried multiple z indexes but made no impact.

Comment: I am not sure but you may try z indexes with 10 digits.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the highest z-index the jqueryUI ever defined is a 9-digit number

Comment: Or 11, if it still doesn't work

Comment: i tried it with 999999999 and with 9999999999 as well but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom helper like this:

```
$('#draggable').draggable({
  zIndex: 20,
  drag: function(event){...},
  helper: function(){
    $("#outerElement").append($("#draggable").clone().attr('id', 'itWorks'))
    return $("#itWorks");
  },
})
```

Where `$("#outerElement")` is the element which contains your `$("#draggable")` and the element where your want to drop as well.